# if deleting top pointer deletes all pointers

Tags: c++

I have a doubt. Let’s say that I have implemented a stack in a way similar to a linked list, like this (there are just a push and a print function)

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
struct node{
    T data;
    node<T> *down;
};

template <class T>
class mystack{
public:
    node<T> *top = new node<T>;
    mystack(){top = nullptr; std::cout << "CONSTRUCTION!" << std::endl;}
    ~mystack(){delete top; std::cout << "DESTRUCTION!" << std::endl;}
    void push(T elem){
        node<T> *new_node = new node<T>;
        new_node -> data = elem;
        if (!top){
            new_node -> down = top; 
            top = new_node;
            return;
        }
        
        else{
            node<T> *temp = top;
            new_node -> down = temp;
            top = new_node;
            return;
        }
    }
        
    void print_stack(){
        node<T> *temp = top;
        while(temp){
            std::cout << temp -> data << std::endl;
            temp = temp -> down;
        }
    }

};

int main(){
    mystack<int> st;
    st.push(20);
    st.push(200);
    st.push(2000);
    st.print_stack();
}
```

my question is: does deleting the top pointer delete all the other pointers or just the first one and the other are still there sitting (hence this code is very bad)?.
Plus, would you rather use a smart pointer to do this kind of stuff? Thank you for your time.

Comment: nope - you'll have to delete them - otherwise thats leaking memory

Comment: It's (also) odd that your constructor immediately leaks `top` by replacing the only pointer to the object created in the default member initializer.

Comment: Unless the destructor of `T` (or destructors of its members, if any) explicitly `delete`s something, then deleting the "top pointer" will not delete anything else.   C++ doesn't have garbage collection built in, so these things won't happen by magic.

Comment: Every `new` ever called must be accompanied by `delete`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your single `delete` is insufficient. You need something like:

```
~mystack()
{
    while(top != nullptr)
    {
        node<T> *curr = top;
        top = top->down;
        delete curr;
    }
    std::cout << "DESTRUCTION!" << std::endl;
}
```

That way, you delete every element in your container.